# WebAPI 2 and RouteDebugger

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm using Vs2012 and installed the Web Tools 2013.1 for VS2012 from here:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41532

I then proceeded by creating a new WebAPI 2 project and installed RouteDebugger from here:
http://www.nuget.org/packages/WebApiRouteDebugger/

When I try to view the routedebugger page using a browser (locahost:xxxx/rd), nothing is displayed.

However, if I created a new MVC4 application using WebAPI and install the RD package, it works fine.

Is there a way to get RouteDebugger to work with WebAPI 2?